# Combine two table column as per Table1 Column value falls in Table 2 column value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 column(Name, Number) in Table1 and 4 column(Name, Min, Max, Color) in Table2.

Table1 column(Number) contain a numeric value for which there is a range in Table2(Min and Max).

My requirement is to pick Name, Number from table1 and Color from table2 on the basis of Name column.

Also if Number value in Table1 is higher then Max value of Table2 then same row value need to pick from Color column.

```
**Table1 sample data:**

**Name  Number**
A       33
B       17


**Table2 sample data:**

**Name  Min   Max    Color**
A       0     20     RED
A       21    44     Yellow
A       45    45     Green
B       0     0.9    Green
B       1     15.99  Yellow
B       16    16     RED

**Output**

**Name  Number  Color**
A       33      Yellow
B       17      Red
```

Please let me know for any confusion on above queries...

**NOTE: This query is for Custom SQL in Tableau, so can't use CTE or else advance methodology.**

Comment: So anything over 45 is green? And an SQLFIDDLE would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , COALESCE(y.color,z.color) color 
  FROM table1 x
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2 y 
    ON y.name = x.name 
   AND x.number BETWEEN y.min AND y.max
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.* 
         FROM table2 a 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT name,MAX(max) max FROM table2 GROUP BY name ) b 
           ON b.name = a.name 
          AND b.max = a.max
     ) z 
    ON z.name = x.name;
```

Comment: I have only question for you, is the coalesce will work with Tableau custom SQL or i can use any other method?
Really appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Aditya I have no idea what tableau is.

Comment: What is d purpose of COALESCE?, as i did google but not success to get actual purpose.

Comment: In the event that there is no corresponding row in table y (in other words, if the table1 number is larger than the corresponding value for table2 max), the query will use the color associated with the largest value. COALESCE is like IFNULL.

Answer (score 0):

Your final condition is rather strange.  However you can simplify the logic:  just ignore the `max` column and choose the last row where the min is less than or equal to the number:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.color
        from table2 t2
        where t1.name = t2.name and t2.min <= t1.number
        order by t2.min desc
        limit 1
       ) as color
from table1 t1;
```

Comment: I am getting below error msg on your query. Reason is Table2 return 3 rows result for a single name row in table1.

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.